# Wordpress plugin 'Floating Links" not displaying right colors

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

To start , my website is http://www.twostonedbirds.org --- So, I have a strange issues here, I have the "Floating Links" installed and I have the colors customized to my liking If you will look you can see in the Developer Dashboard the colors are working just fine... Looks great. [This is how it is supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWuOB.png)

Now, when you visit the homepage... for some odd reason the colors are not applied... I have have been fooling with it for hours and can't get it right :( any help would be greatly appreciated -- here is the pic of how the homepage looks at [messed up plugin, or some sort of error?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQPjx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css. I just added `!important` to all css

```
.floating_next_prev_wrap .floating_links a, .floating_next_prev_wrap .floating_links .disabled {
    background-color: #c8dd23 !important;
    color: #4f168c !important;
    font-size: 22px !important;
}

.floating_next_prev_wrap .floating_links .fl_slimer_Wrap {
    background-color: #c8dd23 !important;
    color: #4f168c !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you wouldnt have any idea how I could make space over on the right hand side and add a youtube like video player/

Comment: I probably need to start a new thread for this i suppose but I figured why waste more time.... this is what i reall after https://i.imgur.com/gHB1bHv.jpg

Comment: you need to change in archive-product.php file in theme folder

Comment: couldi hire you for help on fiverr?

Comment: lets speak on email,  downlifted@gmail.com or you can tell me your fiverr account